# Why does this loop never accept input first time round?

Tags: loops, python-3.x

I'm creating a Caesar Cipher and it works completely but there is one small bug. I have created a code snippet as to not post the whole algorithm. My problem is that when this is ran and you enter 1 or 2 it will not accept your input, but on the second run it will. I am utterly baffled as to why.

```
Choice = input('Encrypt or Decrypt? \n\nEnter 1 for Encrytion \nEnter 2 for Decrytion')

while Choice != '1' or Choice != '2':
    print('You must enter 1 or 2')
    Choice = input('Encrypt or Decrypt? \n\nEnter 1 for Encrytion \nEnter 2 for Decrytion')

    if Choice == '1':
        print('bananas')
        break

    if Choice == '2':
        print ('cake')
        break
```

Comment: In the future please tag your question with the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This will always be true:

```
while Choice != '1' or Choice != '2':
```

Suppose `Choice` was '1'; that will be:

```
while '1' != '1' or '1' != '2':
```

which is:

```
while False or True:
```

which is:

```
while True:
```

For every possible `Choice`. You want:

```
while Choice != '1' and Choice != '2':
```

Actually, you want to put `Choice = input(...` in a loop and only break out of that loop when `Choice == '1' or Choice == '2'`. The comparisons must be done outside the loop as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Joe, your `while` loop is always `True`, and will always print “You must enter 1 or 2” no matter what you type. Try running it in a debugger.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help I tweeked my algorithm an fixed it a different way, but thanks all the same for the help.